# Confirmation box for LinkButton in Gridview before Rowcommand fires

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dialog, rowcommand

I have a `gridview`, and a `linkbutton` on this gridview.

When linkbutton is clicked, `rowCommand` fires, however I want to ask user to comfirm the click with a comfirmation box,

- if yes -> rowCommand fires,
- if no-> nothing happens.

I couldn't find a way to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this as the LinkButton's [`OnClientClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.onclientclick%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property:

```
OnClientClick="return confirm('Do you really want?');"
```

Answer (score 2):

try this.

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow){  
 LinkButton link = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("LinkButton1");    
 link .Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('Are you sure to proceed with this 
action?');");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in my code behind:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    LinkButton del = e.Row.Cells[2].Controls[0] as LinkButton;
    del.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this role?');");
}
```

and in my markup:

```
<asp:GridView
    ID="GridViewRoles"
    runat="server"
    Width="350px"
    EmptyDataText="No Roles"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    AllowPaging="False"
    PageSize="50"
    AllowSorting="True"
    CssClass="gridview"
    AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="even"
    OnRowCommand="GridViewRoles_RowCommand"
    OnRowDataBound="GridViewRoles_RowDataBound"
    OnRowDeleting="GridViewRoles_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="GridViewRoles_RowEditing">
    <Columns>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="Role" HeaderText="Role" SortExpression="Role" HeaderStyle-Width="170px" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <asp:ButtonField CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" HeaderStyle-Width="50px" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />

    </Columns>
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="even" />
</asp:GridView>
```